# Webpage is not Available - Facebook Login Integration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I want to integrate facebook api to help in the registration process in my website. It was working fine before - the standard fb login button appears, the pop-up window to login to fb was working, some of the user data are obtained. However after several trials with me modifying the code as the feature isnt fully integrated yet in my site, whenever I press the login button what replaces the fb login page is "This webpage is not available." I already retracted the modifications I made to the point that it was back to the version wherein it was working before. I also created another app and replaced the app id and secret key, still it displays the same message. I do not know what is wrong. Please help.

Update:
I uploaded the project files to another hosting site and it works! Could it be that the previous domain is now blocked?

Comment: It's working now for me. FB has fixed the bug/s. Thread here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479190/facebook-oauth-dialog-not-redirecting-to-login/18479268#18479268. Previous domain was not blocked.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please read the other posts, dude... we're all waiting for the FB to fix the issue...

Comment: Dudette here. I am looking for similar cases.  Are you saying that this is already an issue? You are experiencing the same?

Comment: As always, FB solved it fairly quickly... 
Facebook: Login Button issues resolved
Last updated: today at 9:15am
As of today at 9:15am

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please, in the next answers recommend adding a comment rather than submit a similar response.